# Image processing resources on Mac with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, image-processing

Can anyone suggest good image processing tutorials/books to start, on Mac using objective-c?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by "image processing." For basic manipulation, see [NSImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/) class and the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). For advanced topics, see the [Core Image Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experiment with Core Image, use the Quartz Composer application to write your GL shaders.  You'll be able to see the effects of changes to your code instantaneously.